# character-number pairs in a list: how to get the numbers when I know the characters/letters?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I want a program that will calculate the numerical value of a name (or any word). So if I have the simple `list_c_a` in the image and my input is, for instance, `robert`, how do I identify the corresponding numerical values of the letters `'r'`, `'o'`, `'b'` and so on so I can add them up? Also: how can I make sure that capital letters (`"R"obert`) will be OK?

```
list_c_a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7), ('h', 8), ('i', 9), ('j', 10), ('k', 11), ('l', 12), ('m', 13), ('n', 14), ('o', 15), ('p', 16), ('q', 17), ('r', 18), ('s', 19), ('t', 20), ('u', 21), ('v', 22), ('w', 23), ('x', 24), ('y', 25), ('z', 26)]
```

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `list` of `tuple`s into a `dict`, and use `sum` with a generator expression and `str.lower` (to allow uppercase characters) to sum the numerical values of all characters in the string:

```
string = 'Robert'

list_c_a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7), ('h', 8), ('i', 9), ('j', 10), ('k', 11), ('l', 12), ('m', 13), ('n', 14), ('o', 15), ('p', 16), ('q', 17), ('r', 18), ('s', 19), ('t', 20), ('u', 21), ('v', 22), ('w', 23), ('x', 24), ('y', 25), ('z', 26)]

dict_c_a = dict(list_c_a)

num = sum(dict_c_a[c] for c in string.lower())

print(num)
```

Output:

```
78
```

Comment: Your solution is compact and elegant -- Thank you! Funny thing is that I learned Python up to the lists/tuples (but I didn't eye the dictionaries) cuz that was all I needed for my cybersecurity project. You just gave me a reason to toy with the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

OK, one more quick question since I'd still like to toy with the lists. I googled around for "python access element in nested list" and there is so much material that I have to navigate for hours to find what I need.

So say I have the list_C at the bottom (26 letters paired with 26 shuffled numbers from 1 to 26). I get the string "michael": how do I get the list of the numerical values corresponding to the letters 'm', 'i', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e' and 'l'? In this particular case the list I'm looking for would be: 
**list_N = [12, 26, 23, 25, 24, 18, 19]**

list_C = [('a', 24), ('b', 9), ('c', 23), ('d', 6), ('e', 18), ('f', 8), ('g', 2), ('h', 25), ('i', 26), ('j', 20), ('k', 16), ('l', 19), ('m', 12), ('n', 3), ('o', 21), ('p', 5), ('q', 7), ('r', 10), ('s', 11), ('t', 1), ('u', 4), ('v', 15), ('w', 22), ('x', 13), ('y', 14), ('z', 17)]

Thanks